# Discord.js check for multiple channels

Tags: discord.js

I am implementing audit logs in my bot.

I want to ask, if its possible to check for multiple channel names.

```
const logs = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "logs");
if (message.guild.me.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS') && !logs) {
    message.guild.channels.create('logs', { type: 'text' });
```

I am using this to check if a log channel exists, but if not, the bot will create one.

I want to add more channel names, because some servers dont have the same name for logs channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking is how to search for multiple names e.g. `logs` or `bot-log` for example. All you need to do is use the OR operator (||) like this:

```js
const logs = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "logs" || channel.name === "bot-log");
```

These operators work in many circumstances e.g. if statements

```js
let foo = 'foo'
let bar = 'bar'

if (foo === 'foo' && bar === 'foo') return //this will never call - the && operator means 'AND'

if (foo === 'foo' || bar === 'foo') return //this WILL call - the || operator means 'OR'
```

Comment: oooh. didnt know it was such a simple thing. Thank you!

Comment: no problem, please mark the answer as correct by clicking the green tick